# merge of two tables from two databases

Tags: sql

thanks for your attention to answer the questions.
How can I merge two tables from different databases?
Thanks again

Comment: Want you merge SELECT results or merge two tables in one ?

Comment: You may have to clarify: Are the tables identical with all fields and field types? Are duplicates possible?

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same amount of columns, the columns have the same types and are in same order, you can simple do something like this (merges `db1.a` and `db2.b` into `c` of the currently selected db):

```
INSERT INTO c SELECT * FROM db1.a;
INSERT INTO c SELECT * FROM db2.b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Little vague in the question...Are you looking for information regarding getting the two databases talking to each other (linked server, replication maybe?)

Or I'll go out on a limb...you've got two tables in different databases and are looking at making it into one table going forward?  The biggest 'gotcha' that I come across during database/table merging are key related issues.  If the table simply has an ID column to keep each record unique, creating a new table and then loading data into the new table (allowing the ID to increment itself) is my preferred route (use insert statements like reko_t has written).  If the table is using data columns to keep the record unique, then you'll need to determine if the data keys remain unique in a merged instance...if you're lucky, the key/key sets will be unique and you can pretty much mash the table together.  Unlucky...you'll need to determine business rules on how to handle the duplicate keys.